# Django form textarea strips newlines

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't make Django displaying properly line breaks in
textareas. I'm using Python 3.4 and Django 1.8.3.

For example, let's say I have a model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
```

And an admin:

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

If add a new product via the admin, with the following description:

```
First line

Second line
```

And hit save, the following value is saved in database (I can access it via django's shell, for example):

```
>>> product.description
'First line\r\n\r\nSecond line'
```

But when I try to edit the same product, the textarea dislays:

```
First line
Second line
```

So if make some modifications on other fields, my line breaks are lost when I hit save.

Sorry for the dumb question, but what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was introduced by the [StripWhitespaceMiddleware](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/StripWhitespaceMiddleware) I had in place to reduce HTML size:

```
class StripWhitespaceMiddleware(object):
    """
    Strips leading and trailing whitespace from response content.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.whitespace = re.compile('^\s*\n', re.MULTILINE)
        self.whitespace_lead = re.compile('^\s+', re.MULTILINE)
        self.whitespace_trail = re.compile('\s+$', re.MULTILINE)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if "text" in response.get('Content-Type', ''):
            response_content = response.content.decode('utf-8')
            if hasattr(self, 'whitespace_lead'):
                response_content = self.whitespace_lead.sub('', response_content)
            if hasattr(self, 'whitespace_trail'):
                response_content = self.whitespace_trail.sub('\n', response_content)

            # Uncomment the next line to remove empty lines
            if hasattr(self, 'whitespace'):
                response_content = self.whitespace.sub('', response_content)
            response.content = response_content.encode('utf-8')

        return response
```

Textareas work as expected when I disable this middleware.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same example and worked fine. 
What's version of django you are using?
The only differenc was when open the django shell, the description is **unicode**.
It would be the problem.
The result was:

```
>>> from product.models import Product
>>> o = Product.objects.all().first()
>>> o.description
u'First Line\r\n\r\nSecond line'
```

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4 and django 1.8.3. Since you cannot reproduce the issue, I musthave introduced it somewhere, thank you for trying :)

Comment: I tested on a python2.7 and django 1.7.2. Great you have solved the problem!